Within Microsoft Word, how do you continue a page number from a different document - not a different section within the same document
is it possible to to continue a page number from a previous document, without manually adjusting the starting page number? I also always want to make sure that the second document starts on an even page number. Example:
Let's call the First document. ABC.doc and the second document 123.doc. These are two separate physical Word files. Let's say document ABC has pages that runs 1-14. Then document 123 would start on page 16, an even number. If I updated document ABC and there are now 15 pages, document 123 will still start on page 16. However, if I update document ABC and there are now 16 pages, then document 123 will also automatically update and start on page 18. Likewise, if I take away a page or two from document ABC, so it ends on page 12, then document 123 will again automatically update and start on page 14.
I have several documents I would like this to work for, if possible, a list of documents continuing where the last left off. I realize, the pages won't update until I open the document itself. But, is this even possible? Yes, I know I can offset the first page of each document, so I can manually edit the number of the first page, but I was wondering if the document itself could automatically update on it's own each time it is opened.
Thanks.

It's great to see from the answer you've gotten that this is possible. One less hacky alternative is to use InDesign and use book files. Admittedly, it doesn't have the word processing features one would want, but presumably adding page numbers is a later step in the process.

Take a look at my Article on the Microsoft Answers site: Using RD and Other Fields
(https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-rd-and-other-fields-to-construct-multi-file/f1c8cd3c-c92d-4dc3-bfb7-84773c8b4dce)
It quotes extensively from an archival copy of an article by Jonathan West.

Unfortunately, what has probably happened is that the page numbers on
each document start at page 1, so the Table of Contents looks a real
mess with the page numbers starting afresh at each document. You
probably want the pages to be numbered consecutively throughout the
document. If the cover page file including the TOC is 5 pages, then
you want chapter1.doc to start at page 6.
To do this by hand is cumbersome, but do-able if you don't have too
many separate files. Open chapter1.doc, and then go to Insert/Page
Numbers. The following dialog will appear.
Image of Page Numbers dialog box.
Click the Format button and the following dialog will appear.
Image of Page Number Format dialog box, which is an extension of the
Page Number dialog, showing the option selected to continue from
previous section.
Click the Start at button, and enter 6 in the box to the right of it
(or whatever you want as your starting page number), and then click OK
to close the dialog. The Page Numbers dialog will have changed to that
it now looks like this. (Note: The Cancel button is now a Close
button.)
Image of the Page Number dialog again, now showing the Cancel button
has changed to a Close button.
Click Close to clear the dialog. Don't click OK, as this will insert
page numbers into the header. I'm assuming that the page numbers are
already there and you don't need another set!
Now you need to move to the end of the document to find out the page
number of the last page. Write it down, you will need it in order to
set the starting page of the next chapter. Now save and close
chapter1.doc.
You then open Chapter2.doc and repeat the whole process, adding 1 to
the page number of the last page of current chapter, in order to set
the starting page for the next chapter. Once you have been through all
the chapters, you can then update the Table of Contents again, and
provided you have made no mistakes anywhere, the page numbers in the
TOC will all be straightened out.
As you can see, this is a somewhat laborious process if you have more
than 2 or 3 documents in the set. Fortunately, this process is an
ideal candidate for a bit of automation; and just to make life easier
for you, I have written the macro that does this. (The code for this
is also in the TechTrax Library, if you want to download it and import
it directly into your template.)
Sub UpdateTocAndPageNumbers()
Dim oField As Field
Dim strCode As String
Dim iLastPage As Long
Dim oDoc As Document

ChDir ActiveDocument.Path
With ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View
    .ShowAll = False
    .ShowHiddenText = False
    .ShowFieldCodes = False
    .Type = wdPrintView
End With
ActiveDocument.Repaginate
Selection.Move unit:=wdStory, Count:=1
iLastPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

For Each oField In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If oField.Type = wdFieldRefDoc Then
        strCode = Trim$(oField.Code)
        strCode = Trim$(Mid$(strCode, InStr(strCode, " ")))
        If LCase$(Left$(strCode, 2)) = "\f" Then
            strCode = Trim$(Mid$(strCode, 3))
        End If
        If LCase$(Right$(strCode, 2)) = "\f" Then
            strCode = Trim$(Left$(strCode, Len(strCode) - 2))
        End If
        If Asc(strCode) = 34 Then
            strCode = Trim$(Mid$(strCode, 2, Len(strCode) - 2))
        End If

        ChDir ActiveDocument.Path
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strCode)
        oDoc.Activate
        With oDoc.ActiveWindow.View
            .ShowAll = False
            .ShowHiddenText = False
            .ShowFieldCodes = False
            .Type = wdPrintView
        End With
        oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary). _
                 PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = True
        oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary). _
                 PageNumbers.StartingNumber = iLastPage + 1
        oDoc.Repaginate
        Selection.Move unit:=wdStory, Count:=1
        iLastPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End If
Next oField
ChDir ActiveDocument.Path
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub

You run this macro when your cover page document is open. It does the
following:
Sets the document so that hidden text and field codes are not displayed.
This makes sure that page numbers displayed on the screen
match what will be printed.
Repaginates the cover page document, and finds out the page number of
the last page.
Finds each RD field in turn. For each field it does the following:
a. opens the associated document,
b. sets the starting page to the appropriate value,
c. repaginates the document,
d. finds out the page number of the last page,
e. saves and closes the document. When all the RD fields have been processed, it updates the fields in the cover page document,
including the Table of Contents.
You may need to run this macro twice, initially. This is because the
process of updating the Table of Contents may change the number of
pages in the cover page document.
The macro will work even for Word 97, where you don't have the \f
switch within the RD fields options. If this is the case, you must
have all the documents of the set in the same folder. I'd recommend
that you do this, anyway

You do not need to have a Table of Contents to use this; I am quoting rather than re-writing. This code would also update an Index.

Thanks for the response, but I’m not using a table of contents. All I’m trying to do is insert page numbers in the footer of the document, which is easy to do. But then I want document 2 to pick up where document 1 left off, but to always start on an even page. Then document 3 to start where document 2 left off, etc. I’m going to be having a lot of documents strung together like this. I’m trying to write a book with each chapter in its own separate document, instead of having 1 document that is hundreds of pages long. Thanks.

@Chris: You don't have to have a table of contents to use this solution (if you have one, it will be updated,  but if you don't it doesn't matter).

I added a note at the end to reflect that while the RD field is used most often to allow a Table of Contents (and Index) in one document to reflect content in other documents, neither an Index nor a Table of Contents are needed for this code to work.
